# Is there a way to count all similar element in the set?

Tags: c++, set, operation

I have two string sets:

```
v1 = {ball,water,example}
v2 = {example,ball,book}
```

How is it possible to compare them in the most efficient way and find similarities, so the result will be some string set, `s1 = {ball, example}`?

Comment: Sort ‘‘em and then use [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: What makes `ball` similar to `book`?

Comment: Does “similar” mean “identical”?  If not, you’ll need to define what you mean by “similar”

Comment: If "similar" does mean "identical", why not simplify "compare them in the most efficient way and find similarities" to "find their intersection efficiently"?

Comment: Your question title asks about *counting* the similar elements, while your question body asks about *finding* the similar elements. While these are related (the former is the size of the latter), it would look better if the title and body were consistent.

Comment: It's absolutly unclear what yo're asking. You need to show some meaningful examples. The example you show isn't meaningful, you forgot to explain why s1 is the result of whatever operatino between v1 et v2.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you simply want to find the intersection between two sets of strings.

You are probably looking for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::set<std::string> v1{ "ball", "water", "example"};
  std::set<std::string> v2{ "example", "ball", "book"};

  std::set<std::string> s1;

  std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
    v2.begin(), v2.end(),
    std::inserter(s1, s1.begin()));

  for (auto str : s1)
    std::cout << str << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
ball example
```

Addmittedly `std::set_intersection` from `<algorithm>` is somewhat arcane for beginners.